# How to create function with case logic in mysql?

Tags: mysql, stored-functions

Trying to create a stored function in MYSQL the defines budget status as Over budget, under budget or on budget. Here is my built function:

```
Delimiter $$

create function budgetCompare (hours dec(10,2), budget FLOAT(11,2), rate Float(7.2)) returns varchar(20)
deterministic
Begin
Declare status_ varchar(20);
    CASE
        when sum(hours * rate)/budget * 100 > 110 THEN Set status_ = "Over Budget";
        when sum(hours * rate)/budget * 100 < 90 THEN SET status_ = "Under Budget";
        else SET status_ = "On Budget";
    END CASE;
RETURN (status_);
END $$

Delimiter ;
```

However when I try to use the error I get an error:

```
select p.projectNo, budgetCompare(hours, budget, rate)
from project as p
join projectteam using (projectNo)
join projectrole using (roleNo)
group by projectNo; 

error: Error Code: 1111. Invalid use of group function
```

I've tried this time of function before and had it work. The function will create but it won't run.

I keep trying to fix it but can't see the forrest through the trees now.

Running the sum(rate * hours)/budget * 100 works in a regular select statement but not with the function.

Comment: MySQL is complaining about the SUM in `when sum(......`.   What are your trying to SUM?  If you remove the `sum()` it will work.

Comment: Your function is scalar, not aggregate. It cannot be used by such way. What tables `hours, budget, rate` are taken from?